# jQuery unpleasant Draggable, Resizable interaction

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

When I resize the first div it causes the next div to jump 'up' the column.

To recreate: top div drag the resize handle.

jQuery

    `$(function() {
    $('.portlet').draggable({ grid: [25, 25] }).resizable({ grid: [25, 25] });
    });`

Layout

```
<div class="portlet" id="P2">
    <div class="portlet-header"><h3>News</h3></div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
<div class="portlet" id="Div1">
    <div class="portlet-header"><h3>Feeds</h3></div>
    <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
</div>
```

CSS

`.portlet
{
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}`

Comment: I made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zGFnC/), but couldn't figure out the problem. The only thing I can say, that is not caused by the .portlet css.

Answer (score 0):

Give #Div1 an absolute positioning of top:100px and it should stay put when resizing #P2. On initial resize of #Div1 it's inline positioning becomes changed and the browser bumps up #Div1 as you describe.