# Resizable and draggable div jumps location on resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the latest jquery and jqueryui as of writing.  I've attached a jsfiddle to demonstrate.  If you drag the test2 block down a few slots, then try to resize the first block, the test2 block jumps up in location.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
Here's the link to the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/FjGwk/
```

Comment: You circumvented the warning about only linking to jsfiddle by putting it in a codeblock. Please make the link clickable and try to find a code sample that is small enough to reproduce the error without other code so it can be placed inline in your post. That way it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Answered [there][1]
Just make position 'absolute' for jumping divs.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326030/jquery-unpleasant-draggable-resizable-interaction